# How to use different pages for form input and results using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So, I have a search form in a php page (top.php) which is an include for the site I'm working on, one php page where all the mySQL stuff happens and the results are stored in a variable and echoed (dosearch.php) and lastly a php page where the results are displayed in a div through jQuery (search.php). This is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var searchVal = $('#search_term').attr('value');
        var categoryVal = $('#category').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'dosearch.php',
            data: "search_term=" + searchVal + "&category=" + categoryVal,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#results_cont').html('');
                $('#loader').html('<img src="layout/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Searching..." />');
                if(!searchVal[0]) {
                    $('#loader').html('');
                    $('#results_cont').html('No input...');     
                    return false;
                }   
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#loader').html('');
                $('#results_cont').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The #search_term and #category fields are in top.php, the other divs (#loader and #results_cont) are in search.php. How would I go by in order to make the form submit and display the results in search.php from the top.php without problems? It works perfectly if the form and javascript are in search.php but I can't seem to separate those and make it work. What am I doing wrong?

PS. Sorry if I'm not clear enough, am at work, really tired. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SPLITTING:**

```
  <? include('functions-or-classes.php'); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
      <title></title>

         <? include('js-script.php'); ?>

      </head>
      <body>

        <? include('results-div.php'); ?>

          <? include('search-form.php'); ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

You should just respect this order then you can split the code in different pieces and include it into your main php file;

PS: peraphs your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <title></title>
  <script> 
$(function() {
    $('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchVal = $('#search_term').val();
        var query = $(this).serialize(); // search_term=lorem&category=foo
        if (!searchVal) {
            $('#results_cont').html('No input...');
        } else {
            $('#results_cont').html('<div id="loader">'+
                 '<img src="layout/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /><div>');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'dosearch.php',
                data: query,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#results_cont').html(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="search-form">
       <input type="text" id="search_term" name="search_term" />
       <select id="category" name="category">
         <option value="foo">foo</option>
         <option value="bar">bar</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" name="search_button" />
  </form>
  <div id="results_cont"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a cleaner and more readable code. var searchVal = $('#search_term').val(); is not really needed though since I'm serializing the form, right? I suppose the biggest problem is (if it's even possible) to separate the form from the page containing the <div id="results_cont"></div>.

Comment: @Alex Berg - the `searchVal` is still needed since we are using it to check if the `search_term` is empty or not; then about the `<div id="results_cont"></div>`, yes, you can place it where you want in the `<body>` tag.

Comment: It's working fine. What if the form was on another page entirely though? How could I somehow store the user input, open the search page and then display the result?

Comment: demo & download http://aseptik.net/php5/demo/how-to-use-different-pages-for-form-input-and-results-using-ajax/ PS you don't need to use AJAX if you want go this way. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your search_button redirect to your search.php an do the work when the pages is loaded instead of doing it on the click event.

and use `$_GET['Search']` on the search page

and your url should look like this

```
/search.php?Search=1337
```

Comment: Ah yes, but what if he's already on the results page? Wouldn't that mean the whole page would reload again?

Comment: Yes it would, but is that really a problem?

Comment: Well, it kind of negates the whole concept of using ajax in order to modify only a part of the page, as I understand it. I could strictly use PHP in order to do that.

Comment: You can make a check if you are already on the page and then do it